# Initializing std::vector with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, c++17

I can do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int size = 5;
    int *array = new int[size];
    load(array);
    std::vector<int> v(array, array+size);
    delete[] array;
}
```

And, with smart porter, this (alt1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> array(new int[size]);
    load(array.get());
    std::vector<int> v(array.get(), array.get()+size);
}
```

And I was wondering, with all this smartness in place, if something even shorter (alt2) would be ok:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> array(new int[size]);
    load(array.get());
    std::vector<int> v(array);
}
```

But compiler says no:

```
c++ -std=gnu++14 -g -Wall -O3  -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:6:19: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<int>'
        std::vector<int> v(array);
```

So, alt1 is the shortest way to init std::vector with unique_ptr?

Comment: You are not initializing with `unique_ptr`. You are simply copying contents of an array into a vector. The fact that the memory occupied by that array is manged by an instance of `unique_ptr` is irrelevant.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is a wrapper that will automatically dispose of the referenced memory when it goes out of scope just so you don't have to call `delete` yourself by the end of the function. Since you did not allocate `std::vector` using a `new` operator, you simply don't need it at all. Plus as pointed out by others, creating an array here is redundant and makes no sense, `std::vector` will manage it's own array internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are equivalent to `std::vector<int> v(size);` -- creating a vector of a specific size and default initializing all the members.  All you are doing with the arrays and unique_ptrs is creating an array with default initialized members and then copying the array into a vector -- default initializing the array directly is simpler.

If you want to load into the vector, you can do that too:

```
std::vector<int> v(size);
load(&v[0]);
```

Comment: Not quite. The original code is garbage-initializing all the elements; the code exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized objects. `std::vector<int> v(size);` on the other hand fills the vector with zeros.

Comment: Slightly modified the code. There is a function loading data into the array, I can’t change this so is not possible to go directly with the vector. Sorry for not mentioning this since the beginning.